# Resize fontawesome icons on change in screen size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Trying to change the size of the icons on a bootstrap grid with following code and the media query but can't seem to make it work.

```css
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .fa-5x {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    h1 {
      color: red;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  }

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    .fa-5x {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    h1 {
      color: red;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="washrooms.php">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
      <center>
        <h3>
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-5x"></i> <br>Washrooms
        </h3>
      </center>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="intermidiate.php"> 
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
      <center>
        <h3>
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i> <br>Shops
        </h3>
      </center>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="intermidiateservice.php">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">  
      <center>
        <h3>
          <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-5x"></i> <br>Services
        </h3>
      </center>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>



</div>
```

The code intends to scale down icon size to fit small screens, but doesn't work.
Can someone help point out what is wrong or help to achieve the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For responsive font size you can use viewport width (vw).

[For further reading](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

PS: this may not support all mobile browsers.

- Help :)

Comment: Thankyou soo soo much for your sweet guidance. It did the job exactly as i desired.